# Converting values in Date Time column into common format

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I have a dataframe with a column containing Date Time values, but the values are in different formats.
I want to bring them all to the format "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm". I tried using the lubridate package to convert the dates with the AM/PM text appended to the dates, but am unable to do so.

```
Date_Time
"11/01/2019 10:00"      
"11/01/2019 11:00"      
"11/01/2019 12:00"      
"11/01/2019 13:00"      
"11/01/2019 14:00"      
"11/01/2019 15:00"      
"11/01/2019 16:00"      
"10/03/2019 23:00"      
"10/04/2019 1:00"
"10/28/2019 05:00:00 AM"
"10/28/2019 10:00:00 PM"
"10/29/2019 02:00:00 AM"
"10/29/2019 03:00:00 AM"
"10/31/2019 01:00:00 PM"
"10/31/2019 02:00:00 PM"
"10/31/2019 10:00:00 PM"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lubridate`'s `parse_date_time` :

```
lubridate::parse_date_time(df$Date_Time, c('mdYHM', 'mdYIMSp'))
#[1] "2019-11-01 10:00:00 UTC" "2019-11-01 11:00:00 UTC" "2019-11-01 12:00:00 UTC"
#[4] "2019-11-01 13:00:00 UTC" "2019-11-01 14:00:00 UTC" "2019-11-01 15:00:00 UTC"
#[7] "2019-11-01 16:00:00 UTC" "2019-10-03 23:00:00 UTC" "2019-10-04 01:00:00 UTC"
#[10]"2019-10-28 05:00:00 UTC" "2019-10-28 22:00:00 UTC" "2019-10-29 02:00:00 UTC"
#[13]"2019-10-29 03:00:00 UTC" "2019-10-31 13:00:00 UTC" "2019-10-31 14:00:00 UTC"
#[16]"2019-10-31 22:00:00 UTC"
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date_Time = c("11/01/2019 10:00", "11/01/2019 11:00", 
"11/01/2019 12:00", "11/01/2019 13:00", "11/01/2019 14:00", "11/01/2019 15:00", 
"11/01/2019 16:00", "10/03/2019 23:00","10/04/2019 1:00","10/28/2019 05:00:00 AM",
"10/28/2019 10:00:00 PM", "10/29/2019 02:00:00 AM", "10/29/2019 03:00:00 AM", 
"10/31/2019 01:00:00 PM", "10/31/2019 02:00:00 PM", "10/31/2019 10:00:00 PM"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```